# Antd Fixed Header In Layout

Tags: javascript, reactjs, antd

With ant.design, what is the right way to apply [Affix](https://ant.design/components/affix/) to [Header in a Layout](https://ant.design/components/layout/)  so that it stays fixed at the top during scroll? Below is an example layout:

```
import { Layout } from 'antd';
const { Header, Footer, Sider, Content } = Layout;

ReactDOM.render(
<div>
  <Layout>
    <Header>Header</Header>
    <Layout>
      <Sider>Sider</Sider>
      <Content>Content</Content>
    </Layout>
    <Footer>Footer</Footer>
  </Layout>
</div>
, mountNode);
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The demo in @benjycui's anwser is published at ant.design site now: https://ant.design/components/layout/#components-layout-demo-fixed

Answer (score 7):

All you need is some CSS to achieve this

```
#header {
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    left:0;
    top:0;
    right: 0;
    z-index: 1000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can just add a fixed height to the external layout and set scrollable content like this:

```
ReactDOM.render(
<div>
    <Layout style={{ height: '100vh' }}>
        <Header>Header</Header>
        <Layout>
            <Sider>Sider</Sider>
            <Content style={{ overflow: 'scroll' }}>Content</Content>
        </Layout>
        <Footer>Footer</Footer>
    </Layout>
</div>,
mountNode);
```

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late but I found myself in the same situation.
As [cannin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/524444/cannin) says in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42345641/antd-fixed-header-in-layout#comment72921611_42899383):

> "...what I was hoping for was a fixed header when there is a toggleable
>   sidebar"

My solution was to nest a new `Layout` in the `Content`, put the `Sider` in the parent layout and the `Header` in the child, then apply to the child the solution already pointed: https://ant.design/components/layout/#components-layout-demo-fixed

```
ReactDOM.render(
<div>
  <Layout>

    <Sider>Sider</Sider>  <- ***

    <Content>

      <Layout>
        <Header>Header</Header>  <- ***
        <Content>Content</Content>
      </Layout>

    </Content>

    <Footer>Footer</Footer>

  </Layout>
</div>
, mountNode);
```

Also, instead of using `position: fixed` I had to use `position: sticky`, otherwise the right side of the top bar goes off-limits:

```
<Header style={{ position: 'sticky', zIndex: 1, width: '100%' }}>
```